# Determine if a specific image is contained within another, with a simple True/False

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to know if a big image contains a small image. The small image can be semi-transparent (similar to watermark, so it's not a fully filled photo). I've tried following different SO answers on this topic, but they're all matching the EXACT photo, but what I am looking for is whether the photo  exists with 80% accuracy as the photo will be a lossy rendered version of the original one.

This is a procedure of how the images I am searching in will be generated:
Use any photo, put a semi-transparent "watermark" on it within Photoshop and save it. Then I want to check if the "watermark" exists within created photo with certain percent of accuracy (80% is good enough).

I've tried using the original template matching example provided on their [docs page](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) but I'm getting barely any match at all.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('photo2.jpeg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('small-image.png', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.7
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('output', img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here are the photos I've been using for the test, as this is something similar I am trying to make a match on.

[small-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSywb.png)
[photo2.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRjQD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the whole watermark will have the same RGB values and the text will have a little different RGB values otherwise this technique will not work. Based on this we can obtain the RGB values of a pixel of the small image and treated it as a mask by using cv2.inRange to find those pixel values in the large image. Similarly a mask is also created for the small image using those pixel values.

```
small = cv2.imread('small_find.png')
large = cv2.imread('large_find.jpg')
pixel = np.reshape(small[3,3], (1,3))
lower =[pixel[0,0]-10,pixel[0,1]-10,pixel[0,2]-10]
lower = np.array(lower, dtype = 'uint8')
upper =[pixel[0,0]+10,pixel[0,1]+10,pixel[0,2]+10]
upper = np.array(upper, dtype = 'uint8')
mask = cv2.inRange(large,lower, upper)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(small, lower, upper)
```

I had to take a buffer value of 20 because the values were not clearly matching in the large image otherwise only 1 is enough in either upper or lower. Then we find contours in mask and find values of its bounding rectangle which is cut out and reshaped to the size of mask2.

```
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cv2.drawContours(large, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 1)
cnt = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
wanted_part = mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]
wanted_part = cv2.resize(wanted_part, (mask2.shape[1], mask2.shape[0]), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

[image: Output]

The two masks side by side (inverted them otherwise they were not visible).

For comparing they you can use any parameter and check whether it satisfies your condition or not. I used mean square error and got error of only 6.20 which is very low.

```
def MSE(img1, img2):
    squared_diff = img1 - img2
    summed = np.sum(squared_diff)
    num_pix = img1.shape[0] * img1.shape[1] #img1 and 2 should have same shape
    err = summed / num_pix
    return err
```